# npm lock-file lock down the package version

Tags: npm

At work, we start to do the following by lock down the package.json version

```
"little-state-machine": "2.14.1",
```

instead of the following:

```
"little-state-machine": "^2.14.1",
```

I find it strange and annoying, as I thought npm package-lock file is what's that intended to do just like yarn lock file. [Reference](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-locks)

Is there any chance that npm package-lock file will not lock the current version and picking up the latest patch? To manually update the package.json file is redundant and annoying from my point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`package-lock.json` will lock it for developer installations. `npm-shrinkwrap.json` will lock it for end user installations as well. So, depending on whose dependencies you're trying to pin down, you can use one or the other.

The one case I know of for doing it in `package.json` is if you only want to pin some of your dependencies but not all of them.

Comment: I guess as long as we are using npm ci, then in the CI it will include the locked version right? I am getting confused about why we changing package.json that at work.

Comment: `npm ci` will install what is specified in `package-lock.json`.